# How to change date format coming from database to android

Tags: android, mysql, json, date, format

In my android application, I'm parsing data from mysql database using JSON and displaying in android listview. In mysql database, the date format is `YYYY-MM-DD` and I am getting this format in android using JSON as a String. Is it possible to change date format to `DD-MM-YYYY` in android instead of database..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert date form one format to another format :

```
SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MM-YYYY");
try{
    Date d = df1.parse(DateString);
    System.out.println("new date format " + df2.format(d));
}catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Use `SimpleDateFormat` :

```
String inputPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
String outputPattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern);
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);

Date date = null;
String result = null; 

try {
    date = inputFormat.parse(time);
    result = outputFormat.format(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//use the result variable as you wish
```

Comment: Please check you output format is wrong as per question required dd-MM-yyyy and you use dd-MMM-yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

this will be the answer i need :D

```
   String well=String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
   java.util.Locale.getDefault()).format(new java.util.Date()));
```